# log_file command not logging the output of a command in Expect script

Tags: expect

I'm running a debug command to log the output of my command to a file.I tried the log_file command but it doesnt log the output.My code is as follows:

```
log_file -a gdb.txt 
send "~/debugulator.sh $file mns20\r"
log_user 0
expect -re {DSP.*0x[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
log_user 1
send_log $expect_out(0,string)
log_file
```

But when I open gdb.txt,nothing is inside.Can somebody tell me where exactly am I going wrong.The version of expect I'm using is 5.26.0

**UPDATE**
Here is the other piece of code I was trying...It still doesnt work..I have posted the output after adding the exp_internal 1 command..The code is as follows:

```
spawn telnet 10.1.1.2
expect "Login:"
send "xyz\r"
expect "Password:"
send "Nxyz1\r"
expect "xyz:/home/xyz>"
send "cd /sonus/support/GSX-[lindex $argv 0]\r"
log_file myfile.log
send_log "this is in the log file \n"
log_file
interact
```

**OUTPUT**
    `spawn telnet 10.1.1.2`
    `parent: waiting for sync byte`
    `parent: telling child to go ahead`
    `parent: now unsynchronized from child`
    `spawn: returns {17179}`

```
`expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? no`
`Trying 10.1.1.2...`

`expect: does "Trying 10.1.1.2...\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? no`
`Connected to 10.1.1.2.`
`Escape character is '^]'.`

`expect: does "Trying 10.1.1.2...\r\nConnected to 10.1.1.2.\r\nEscape     character is '^]'.\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? no`


`SunOS 5.9`


`expect: does "Trying 10.1.1.2...\r\nConnected to 10.1.1.2.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n\r\n\r\nSunOS 5.9\r\n\r\r\n\r" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? no
login: xyz\r`
`expect: does "Trying 10.1.1.2...\r\nConnected to 10.1.1.2.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n\r\n\r\nSunOS 5.9\r\n\r\r\n\rlogin: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? no`
`expect: timed out`
`send: sending "xyz\r" to { exp6 }`

`expect: does "Trying 10.1.1.2...\r\nConnected to 10.1.1.2.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n\r\n\r\nSunOS 5.9\r\n\r\r\n\rlogin: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Password:"? no
```

xyz`

```
 `expect: does "Trying 10.1.1.2...\r\nConnected to 10.1.1.2.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n\r\n\r\nSunOS 5.9\r\n\r\r\n\rlogin: xyz\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Password:"? no`
 `Password:` 
 `expect: does "Trying 10.1.1.2...\r\nConnected to 10.1.1.2.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n\r\n\r\nSunOS 5.9\r\n\r\r\n\rlogin: xyz\r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Password:"? yes`
 `expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Password:"`
 `expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"`
 `expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying 10.1.1.2...\r\nConnected to 10.1.1.2.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n\r\n\r\nSunOS 5.9\r\n\r\r\n\rlogin: xyz\r\nPassword:"`
 `send: sending "Nxyz1\r" to { exp6 }`

 `expect: does " " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "xyz:/home/xyz>"? no`


 `expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "xyz:/home/xyz>"? no`
 `Last login: Tue May 31 05:10:20 from 10.253.6.98
 /home/xyz/.aliases: No such file or directory.`
 `[1]slate:xyz:/home/xyz>` 
 `expect: does " \r\nLast login: Tue May 31 05:10:20 from 10.253.6.98\r\n/home/xyz/.aliases: No such file or directory.\r\n\u001b]0;[slate:]/home/xyz\u0007[1]slate:\u001b[1mxyz\u001b[m:/home/xyz> " (spawn_id exp6) `match      glob pattern "xyz:/home/xyz>"? no
 `expect: timed out`
 `send: sending "cd /sonus/support/GSX-5\r" to { exp6 }`
 `tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1`
 `spawn id exp6 sent <c>`
 `cspawn id exp6 sent <d /sonus/support/GSX-5\r\r\n\u001b]0;[slate:]/sonus/support/GSX-5\u0007[2]slate:\u001b[1msdwarampudi\u001b[m:/sonus/support    /GSX-5> >`
 `/sonus/support/GSX-5`
`[2]slate:xyz:/sonus/support/GSX-5>`
```

Comment: Add `exp_internal 1` and share the output

Comment: on checking the diagnostics,it is not even going to the log_file command.

Comment: When I tried something as simple as this... `log_file myfile.log
send_log "this is in the log file \n"
log_file`    even this isnt getting logged...

Comment: That should work. What is your `expect` version ? Windows or Linux ?

Comment: expect version is 5.26.0 and its an Ubuntu PC...

Comment: Please check the  update above @Dinesh

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I had this problem too, eventually gave up with this whole thing and redirected the command output to a file then processed it after expect to remove relevant lines. You could even write out some text at the beginning and end of the relevant part, then use a suitable `grep` to extract that part from the resulting file.

Answer (score 0):

Your prompt has colour codes that are causing the pattern match to fail:

```
expect: does "...slate:\u001b[1mxyz\u001b[m:/home/xyz> " (spawn_id exp6) `match      glob pattern "xyz:/home/xyz>"? no
# .................................^^^^^^^^........................................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Often when I ssh to a remote host, the first thing I'll do is (assuming the remote shell is sh/ksh/bash) set the prompt to something that's easy to match:

```
spawn ssh remotehost
# ... password stuff
# now, set the prompt
send "PS1='>'\r"
expect -re {>$}    # use this to match the prompt from now on
```

Actually, all you need to do is simplify your prompt matching: your prompt ends with a `>` and a space, so:

```
expect -re {> $}
```

Comment: ok cool..i did that..but how about the log file?It doesnt have anything to do with the logging right?!?