# How to log the "exec" command's result into log_file from an expect script

Tags: expect

I want to capture progress of my expect script with `log_file` command. After issuing following commands in an expect shell everything is captured in the log file.

```
expect1.1> log_file my.log
expect1.2> exec timedatectl status
      Local time: St 2017-04-19 17:07:10 CEST
                ⋮ 
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

But running following script leaves me with empty log.

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
log_file mylog.log
exec timedatectl status
```

How do I capture a log from an Expect script?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540520/), the answer unfortunately does not deal with logging part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the output and send it to log file explicitly:

```
set output [exec echo hello world]
send_log $output
```

I think the reason that it can automatically log the `exec` result to `log_file` is (according to `man tclsh`):

> If invoked with no arguments then it runs interactively, reading Tcl commands from standard input and **printing command results and error messages to standard output**.

Sounds like `log_file` would capture all data written to the tty but in the script (non-interactive mode) the result of `exec` would not be automatically printed to tty.

Comment: This indeed is working. But why does the log capture everything if a command is run from a shell and why do I have to explicitly use `send_log` while running in a script? And how do I implicitly log from a script?